# Add timeout to connection with Tornado TCPClient

Tags: python, tornado

How can I add a timeout to connecting to a remote server with `tornado.tcpclient.TCPClient.connect`?

#### What I've tried

```
In [1]: from tornado import gen

In [2]: from tornado.tcpclient import TCPClient

In [3]: from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

In [4]: from datetime import timedelta
In [5]: client = TCPClient()
In [6]: IOLoop.current().run_sync(
           lambda: gen.with_timeout(timedelta(seconds=1), 
                                    client.connect('bad-host', 8382)))
gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

This takes well over a second to terminate.  Perhaps I'm using `gen.with_timeout` improperly?  Perhaps something special happenss in the `connect` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the problem has to do with blocking DNS resolution. The default `Resolver` in Tornado is blocking, which means that timeouts can't fire during the resolution process. Try configuring one of the alternate resolvers listed in http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/netutil.html#tornado.netutil.Resolver:

```
tornado.netutil.Resolver.configure('tornado.netutil.ThreadedResolver')
```

The reason these are not the default is that they all require non-standard dependencies: `ThreadedResolver` needs the `futures` package (on Python 2), `TwistedResolver` needs `twisted`, and `CaresResolver` needs `pycares`. I think `ThreadedResolver` works better than the other two in mixed IPv4/IPv6 environments.

Comment: Indeed.  This results in a timeout error after one second.  I'm quite happy to rely on futures, so this resolves my issue.  Thanks!